# Keeping Google login persistent on reloading single page react app

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, persistence, frontend, google-signin

I am currently working on a making a `react-redux` application and it uses Google login to authenticate the user.

The app uses [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) implemented as follows:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>

            <h2> Find destinations ✈️</h2>

            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={this.googleClientId}
                buttonText="Sign-in with Google"
                onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
            />

        </div>
    );
}
```

Currently if I run this code, on clicking the login button, I am able to access the sign in tokens and other user information hence allowing logging in but if I reload the page, this is lost as the app is brought back to original state.

How do I keep the Google login using OAuth2 persistent even after a reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `localStorage` which is available as a `window` object. Upon retrieving the user information from `Google OAuth`, I saved the relavant pieces such as email, name etc. in the `localStorage`; this is done as follows:

***Set* key in localStorage**
*(eg. inside onLogin())*:

```
localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(loginResponse));
```

***Get* key value from localStorage**
*(eg. inside constructor())*:

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
```

***Clear* localStorage**
*(eg. inside onLogout())*:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: I would highly recommend not to store auth tokens and other auth related information in local storage since your auth information can be accessed by any js.